# The Born-Infeld theory and the dominant energy condition

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I was reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0008052v2) by G. Gibbons. Inside, he states that for a theory to satisfy the dominant energy condition (DEC) the trace of the energy-momentum tensor should be positive and the derivative of the Lagrangian w.r.t. the Lorentz invariant scalar $x=F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$ should be strictly negative, i.e. that
$$\partial_x\mathcal{L}<0\qquad\text{and}\qquad \mathcal{L}-x\,\partial_x\mathcal{L}-y\,\partial_y\mathcal{L}\geq 0\,.$$
Here, $y=\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}F_{\mu\nu}F_{\rho\sigma}$ is the second Lorentz invariant. For the case of Born-Infeld Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}_{BI}=-1+\sqrt{1-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y^2}{64}}$, I was able to show that the first condition is satisfied. However, when I try to see whether the second one is satisfied, I find that it only holds up to quadratic order. In other words, expanding the square root into a power series leads to higher orders, e.g. $\mathcal{O}(xy^2)$, for which the second inequality above does not hold.

Is this a well-known feature of the Born-Infeld theory or have I done some mistake?